# Conditional merge, based an event happening between two panel observations

Tags: r, merge, data.table, dcast

I have a panel dataset: `panel` and a dataset with a list of events: `Events`. For the panel dataset, an equal `panelID` shows that two observations belong together.

```
panelID = c(1:50)   
year= c(2001:2010)
country = c("NLD", "GRC", "GBR")

n <- 2

library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
Panel <- data.table(panelID = rep(sample(panelID), each = n),
                 country = rep(sample(country, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                 year = c(replicate(length(panelID), sample(year, n))),
                 some_NA = sample(0:5, 6),                                             
                 some_NA_factor = sample(0:5, 6),         
                 norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                 Income = round(rnorm(10,-5,5),2),
                 Happiness = sample(10,10),
                 Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                 Age = sample(100,100),
                 Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))        
Panel[, uniqueID := .I]                                                                        # Creates a unique ID     
Panel[Panel == 0] <- NA    


Events <- fread(
"Event_Type  country year   
A   NLD   2005
C   NLD   2004       
A   GBR   2006
B   GBR   2003   
A   GRC   2002             
D   GRC   2007",
header = TRUE)
```

================================================================================
EDIT:

```
Events <- fread(
"Event_Type  country year   
A   NLD   2005
A   NLD   2004       
A   GBR   2006
A   GBR   2003   
A   GRC   2002             
A   GRC   2007",
header = TRUE)
```

EDITED DESIRED OUTCOME:

```
panleID country year 2002  2003  2004 2005 2006 2007 
1       NLD     2002 NA    NA    1    1    NA   NA 
1       NLD     2006 NA    NA    1    1    NA   NA
```

=======================================================================

I would like the value in the column `Event_Type` to be added to `Panel`, if the `year` of the event is between two panel observation (and in the same country).

As an example, let's take the following panel observation:

```
panleID country year
1       NLD     2002
1       NLD     2006
```

`Panel` will get 4 extra columns `A` to `D`. The column `A`, will get a `1` in the column if the event in country `NLD` in the year 2005 (first line `Events`, takes place in one of or between the two years. Since it does this results in the following:

```
panleID country year A  B  C  D 
1       NLD     2002 1  NA NA NA
1       NLD     2006 1  NA NA NA
```

I know that merging with the same year goes as follows:

```
merge(Panel, dcast(Events, iso + country ~ Event_Type),
      by = c("country", "year"))
```

But how should I make the merge if I want the values to be equal to or in between the two `panelID` years?

Comment: in your example, in 2004 thare is event `C` in NLD also, that is between 2002 and 2006 of panleID ... why A == 1, but C == NA in your result?

Comment: I just tried to give a very simple example. Apparently a bit too simple ;) C should also be 1 in that case. My apologies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a go at your problem using `data.table`
The code can be shortened, but I always find it useful (expecially on SO) to show all steps in between for easy error-checking and validation.

```
#first, summarise Panel, to get the time-span of the panelID
Panel.short <- Panel[, .(country = unique(country), 
                         start = min(year), 
                         end = max(year) ), 
                     by = .(panelID)]
#    panelID country start  end
# 1:       1     NLD  2002 2006

#perform left non-equi join
Panel.short.joined <- Events[ Panel.short, on =.(country, year >= start, year <= end), mult = "all"][]
#    Event_Type country year year.1 panelID
# 1:          A     NLD 2002   2006       1
# 2:          C     NLD 2002   2006       1

#cast to wide
Panel.final <- dcast( Panel.short.joined, 
       panelID + country ~ Event_Type, 
       fun.aggregate = length )
#    panelID country A C
# 1:       1     NLD 1 1

#perform update join on the original Panel
Panel[, `:=`(A=0, B=0, C=0, D=0)][ 
  Panel.final, 
  `:=`( A = i.A, C = i.C),   # <- add B = i.B and D = i.D here 
  on = .( panelID )][]
#    panelID country year A B C D
# 1:       1     NLD 2002 1 0 1 0
# 2:       1     NLD 2006 1 0 1 0
```

Comment: updated the last line, to initialise A, B, C and D before the actual update-join.

Comment: I have been trying to adapt you answer to the EDIT Events and desired output, (because I made a mistake in the example) but I am doing something wrong. Is there anyway you could show me how your answer looks like for the EDIT?

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to @Wimpel but changes the order to:

1. Cast `Events` to wide
2. Update by reference the year range by `panelID`
3. Non-equi update join

```
# cast Event 
Events_cast <- dcast(Events, country + year~Event_Type, length)

# update by reference for join later
Panel[, `:=`(start = min(year), end = max(year)), by = panelID]

# dcast sorts the rhs alphabetically
cols <- sort(unique(Events[['Event_Type']]))

# non-equi update join
Panel[Events_cast,
      on = .(country,
             start <= year,
             end >= year),
      (cols) := mget(cols)]

#clean up data frame
setnafill(Panel, fill = 0L, cols = cols)
Panel[, `:=`(start = NULL, end = NULL)]

Panel
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have a quick question. I have been trying to adapt you answer to the EDIT `Events` and desired output, (because I made a mistake in the example) but I am doing something wrong. is there anyway you could show me how your answer looks like for the EDIT?

Comment: I have tried to change it to `Events_cast <- reshape2::dcast(Events, country + year ~ year, length, value.var="year")`, which looks good. But at the `# non-equi update join` I get the error: `Error in [.data.table (Panel, Events, on = .(country,  : 
  LHS of := appears to be column positions but are outside [1,ncol] range. New columns can only be added by name.`

Comment: I made a new post for clarity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047386/dcast-merge-based-on-a-column-with-a-value-within-a-certain-range

Answer (score 0):

I would consider making use of 'between' and '.SD'. Having trouble following your example, so typically:

> DT[between(startYear, endYear, incbounds=FALSE,][, dcast(,.SD, cat1 ~
>   cat2 ...)]

Note: By passing data.table to cast with .SD, you can use i to subset further.