# Dcast/merge based on a column, with a value within a certain range

Tags: r, merge, data.table, dcast

I have a panel dataset: panel and a dataset with a list of events: Events. For the panel dataset, an equal panelID shows that two observations belong together.

```
panelID = c(1:50)   
year= c(2001:2010)
country = c("NLD", "GRC", "GBR")

n <- 2

library(data.table)
set.seed(123)
Panel <- data.table(panelID = rep(sample(panelID), each = n),
                 country = rep(sample(country, length(panelID), replace = T), each = n),
                 year = c(replicate(length(panelID), sample(year, n))),
                 some_NA = sample(0:5, 6),                                             
                 some_NA_factor = sample(0:5, 6),         
                 norm = round(runif(100)/10,2),
                 Income = round(rnorm(10,-5,5),2),
                 Happiness = sample(10,10),
                 Sex = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2),
                 Age = sample(100,100),
                 Educ = round(rnorm(10,0.75,0.3),2))        
Panel[, uniqueID := .I]                                                                        # Creates a unique ID     
Panel[Panel == 0] <- NA    

Events <- fread(
"Event_Type  country year   
A   NLD   2005
A   NLD   2004       
A   GBR   2006
A   GBR   2003   
A   GRC   2002             
A   GRC   2007",
header = TRUE)
```

I want to know how often `Events` happen between the panel obervations, split out per year. As an example, for the panel observations with `panelID == 2`, in the country NLD there are two events, in or in between the `years` of that panel observation, namely in 2004 and 2005. Hence:

DESIRED OUTPUT:

```
panleID country year 2002  2003  2004 2005 2006 2007 
2       NLD     2004 NA    NA    1    1    NA   NA 
2       NLD     2007 NA    NA    1    1    NA   NA
```

Based on the solution by [Cole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58890738/conditional-merge-based-an-event-happening-between-two-panel-observations) I tried to do the following:

```
# cast Event 
Events_cast <- reshape2::dcast(Events, country + year ~ year, length, value.var="year")

# update by reference for join later
Panel[, `:=`(start = min(year), end = max(year)), by = panelID]

# dcast sorts the rhs alphabetically
cols <- sort(unique(Events[['year']]))

# non-equi update join
Panel[Events_cast,
      on = .(country,
             start <= year,
             end >= year),
      (cols) := mget(cols)]

#clean up data frame
setnafill(Panel, fill = 0L, cols = cols)
Panel[, `:=`(start = NULL, end = NULL)]

Panel
```

But at the `# non-equi update join` I get the error: `Error in [.data.table (Panel, Events, on = .(country, : LHS of := appears to be column positions but are outside [1,ncol] range. New columns can only be added by name.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) is trying to use the years to figure out which column you are selecting. The error is telling you `2006` and other years are not valid column numbers. The fix is easy:

```
cols <- as.character(sort(unique(Events[['year']])))
```

And here's everything together with a few other changes including:

1. Using `data.table::dcast` instead of `reshape2::dcast`
2. Adding `start` and `end` to the `Events` data.table and casting with those columns.

```
# cast Event 
# Events_cast <- reshape2::dcast(Events, country + year ~ year, length, value.var="year")
Events[, `:=`(start = min(year), end = max(year)), by = country]
Events_cast <- dcast(Events, country + start + end~ year, length)

# update by reference for join later
Panel[, `:=`(start = min(year), end = max(year)), by = panelID]

# dcast sorts the rhs alphabetically
cols <- as.character(sort(unique(Events[['year']])))

# non-equi update join
# Panel[Events_cast,
#       on = .(country,
#              start <= year,
#              end >= year),
#       (cols) := mget(cols)]

Panel[Events_cast,
      on = .(country,
             start <= start,
             end >= end),
      (cols) := mget(cols)]

#clean up data frame
setnafill(Panel, fill = 0L, cols = cols)
Panel[, `:=`(start = NULL, end = NULL)]

Panel
```